# "pywhatskit" on python not sending message

Tags: python, message, whatsapp, send

Using the module pywhatkit you can send messages on WhatsApp,

I used the script:

```
import pywhatkit as w

w.sendwhatmsg("xxxxxxxx", " this is a generated msg",9,26)
```

x is the number

The problem is, all it does is load the message in WhatsApp's textbox, it does not send. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5):

```
import pywhatkit as w
import time
import pyautogui
import keyboard as k
w.sendwhatmsg("your number", 'hi', 8, 38)
pyautogui.click(1050, 950)
time.sleep(2)
k.press_and_release('enter')
```

by pyautogui.click you can adjust cursor to message box and then it will click on it
and after that with keyboard you can click enter as simple as that

Answer (score 5):

I just had the same issue, and I uninstalled and installed again pywhatkit with the following commands:

```
pip uninstall pywhatkit
```

```
pip install pywhatkit
```

I know this question is old, hope it will help someone with the same problem

Answer (score 4):

you must increase the waiting time to more than or equal to 30 seconds, it happens generally due to slow internet. write it like this:

```
import pywhatkit as py
py.sendwhatmsg("+91xxxxxxxxxx", "hello", 13, 12, 32)
```

Comment: By increasing wait time value it works, thanks

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in Pywhatkit: https://github.com/Ankit404butfound/PyWhatKit/issues/20

Comment: According the the issue, the problem should be fixed now

Answer (score 1):

the module currently only supports 1 screen, if you are using multiple screens and the new whatsapp web is currently opening on a separate window from where your code is running is going to give you that error. It is a known issue therefore if you are going to use more than one screen (who isn't) ensure your editor of choice (ie: google chrome and visual studio) are on the same screen.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the window in which pywhatkit opens Whatsapp Web is not selected. When it opens Whatsapp Web, waits for a few seconds and clicks 'enter', the 'enter' is not processed by the browser window. Add the following code to your program:

```
# Import Libraries
import pywhatkit
import pyautogui
from tkinter import *

win = Tk() # Some Tkinter stuff
screen_width = win.winfo_screenwidth() # Gets the resolution (width) of your monitor
screen_height= win.winfo_screenheight() # Gets the resolution (height) of your monitor

print(screen_width, screen_height) # prints your monitor's resolution

pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg("+91xxxxxxxxxx", "Enter Message", 0, 0) # Sends the message
pyautogui.moveTo(screen_width * 0.694, screen_height* 0.964) # Moves the cursor the the message bar in Whatsapp
pyautogui.click() # Clicks the bar
pyautogui.press('enter') # Sends the message
```

No matter what screen you are using, pyautogui will always send your message except if Whatsapp updates its UI. In case this happens, then check where the message bar is located through pyautogui and whatever values you get, divide it by your screen's resolution. This way, it will work on any monitor.

Answer (score 0):

After debugging `sendwhatmsg` function is doing the following things

1. opening your default browser using this query `web.open(f"https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone={phone_no}&text={quote(message)}")`
2. clicking here pg.click(core.WIDTH / 2, core.HEIGHT / 2)
3. and pressing enter pg.press("enter")

The main problem is that this 2 variables `core.WIDTH` and `core.HEIGHT` gives you the resolution of your screen, not the resolution of the tab just opened in the browser. So if the browser tab its not maximized you might end up clicking somewhere else. So please make sure that your browser its maximized when opening.

Answer (score 0):

Even i'm trying to do something same with pywhatkit, but actually i found out that when the message i.e. the string is long enough, it wont get sent automatically, it would need to be pressed enter to send the message. If the message is just one line or something, it is getting sent automatically.

here is a code you can try rather than writing time in the sendwhatmsg function

`w.sendwhatmsg_instantly("Phone_number_with_isd_code", "Your message which you want to send")`

Answer (score -4):

you can do it like this :

```
import pywhatkit as kit
kit.sendwhatmsg('+966********','hi from Python Watsapp Bot',10,56)
```

Comment: This answer is not adding any value. Questioner has know everything shared here